# Серверная проверка In App Billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Пытался добавить в свое приложение покупки. Без проверки покупки работают замечательно, однако, добавив серверную проверку, каждая моя попытка приобрести предмет оборачивалась неудачей.

Слышал где-то, что серверная проверка IAP не работает на тестовых покупках. Так ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, это не так. Скорее всего вы сами у себя же и пытаетесь купить - а это запрещено. Заведите тестовый аккаунт, заведите тестеров в консоли девелопера и покупайте.

[Подробнее здесь](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: Нашел небольшую ошибку в своем коде. Исправил, зашел с тестового аккаунта, и все заработало. Спасибо огромное!